# Is there a better way to make this function return true as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS logic that I am trying to implement, and now pondering why it is not working: I have two arrays with at least one similar element in them, but implementing the logic returned `false` - but I was expecting the opposite result. Please take a look:

```
 const array_one = [
  "Apparel",
  "Footwear",
];

const array_two = [
  "Soap",
  "Footwear",
];


const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  };

  console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two)); //logs false to the console, was expecting 'true'.
```

Comment: what do you want your function to do? its not clear what you want

Comment: Your code checks two arrays for ***equality*** and since they are different you get `false`.

Comment: I want the function to compare elements in each array and see if one exists in another.

Comment: You are returning as soon as you find a mismatch. You should return true if/when you find a match, but otherwise return false.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if any value from one array exists in another array:

```js
const array_one = [ "Apparel", "Footwear", ]; const array_two = [ "Soap", "Footwear", ];
const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return arr1.some(value => arr2.includes(value));
  }
};

console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two)); //true
```

2. Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```js
const array_one = [ "Apparel", "Footwear", ]; const array_two = [ "Soap", "Footwear", ];
const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return arr1.filter(value => arr2.includes(value)).length > 0;
  }
};

console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two)); //true
```

3. Using the `some` method with the `Set` which is more performant since it has an average time complexity of O(n) for the `has` method, and does not require iterating through the entire array.

```js
const array_one = [ "Apparel", "Footwear", ]; const array_two = [ "Soap", "Footwear", ];

const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    const set = new Set(arr2);
    return arr1.some(value => set.has(value));
  }
};

console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two)); //true
```

4. Using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```js
const array_one = [ "Apparel", "Footwear", ]; const array_two = [ "Soap", "Footwear", ];

const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return arr1.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator || arr2.includes(value), false);
  }
};

console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two)); //true
```

Note: methods 1. `filter` and 2. `reduce` are less performant , since they create new arrays, accumulate values, which can be memory-intensive and slow for larger arrays.

Comment: Thank you. Very much appreciated. I have soooo much to learn "Me Lord" :)

Answer (score 1):

Just flip your logic around.

- Make `false` the default assumption
- Create a `Set` for each input `Array` for `O(1)` lookup
- Check if the current item in the set exists in the other and immediately return `true`

```js
const
  array_one   = [ "Apparel" , "Footwear" ],
  array_two   = [ "Soap"    , "Footwear" ],
  array_three = [ "Apple"   , "Orange"   ];

const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false; // lengths must match
  }
  const
    set1 = new Set(arr1),
    set2 = new Set(arr2);
  for (const [value] of set1.entries()) {
    if (set2.has(value)) {
      return true; // short-circuit with true
    }
  }
  return false; // default assumption
};

console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two));   // true
console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_three)); // false
```

If you think `Set` is overkill, you can always use `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
const
  array_one   = [ "Apparel" , "Footwear" ],
  array_two   = [ "Soap"    , "Footwear" ],
  array_three = [ "Apple"   , "Orange"   ];

const checkArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false; // lengths must match
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr2.includes(arr1[i])) {
      return true; // short-circuit with true
    }
  };
  return false; // default assumption
};

console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_two));   // true
console.log(checkArray(array_one, array_three)); // false
```